# SuiteCRM Permissions Issue

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, chmod

On an Ubuntu 14.04.05 (Trusty) server running in AWS, I am trying to install SuiteCRM. The webserver is Plesk.

The directory is /var/www/vhosts/*domain.com*/httpdocs/crm

I cannot get the installer to go past the system check: it says '/cache' is not writeable. I have set chmod -R 775 on /cache and it still fails.

Browsing around, all instructions I can find say to chmod 755 or 775, yet neither work.

Owner is root (as is all the other files in the folder)

I don't know what to do next - any suggestions?[image: Screenshot of error]

Oh, and the 'help' and 'installation guide' and 'support forums' links? USELESS - not a single reply at all after several attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Ownership was the issue. No web directory should be owned by root! should have seen that myself (duh)

I did `chown -R webadmin:psacln crm` and the rest worked like clockwork.